# How to get upto particluar digit level in js

Tags: javascript, truncation

I am new to js.I search on googled too, but I none worked for me.

I have a var  `num = 71.666666666`

How can I limit this to **71.66**

I tried this :

```
Math.tranc(num,2)     # 71

and 

Math.round(num.2)     # 72
```

And also plese suggest me if there are any other methods in js to do this.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

```js
var num = 71.6666666;

a = Math.round(num * 100) / 100

console.log("output :",a);
```

Comment: Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2")

Comment: But your output : 71.67.. I just want 71.66

Comment: Then use Math.trunc(num * 100) / 100, just to trancate

Comment: Thanks it worked. and are there any more methods to do this?